# Is there a free way to set up GitHub 2FA without a mobile device?

Tags: github, two-factor-authentication

I currently don't have a working mobile device but need to switch to 2FA for GitHub.

The only way I currently know to do this is to purchase a Skype phone number and use it for SMS authentication. But that costs money and there's a risk that I'll accidentally let the subscription lapse.

Are there any no-cost ways of authenticating that don't require a mobile device or a working phone number?

Comment: You could always use a FIDO Security key. Although not free it's cheaper than a smart phone and more secure than SMS 2FA. I personally use a Yubico YubiKey 5 NFC and an older Yubikey Neo as a backup.

Answer (score 5):

You can use any open-source password manager that can generate 2FA codes such as [KeePassXC](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc). First you have to install and configure the KeePassXC programme on your local machine, then login to your  Github account and enable two-factor authentication from the *settings > Password and authentication*. Get your `two-factor secret` by clicking the phrase `setup key` right after *Setup authenticator app* above the *QR code*. Paste your `two-factor secret` on your KeePassXC database by right clicking your Github entry *TOTP > Set up TOTP* and place the secret code under `Secret Key` input box, use the Default settings (RFC 6238) for the mean time then click **OK**. Verify your secret code by going again to your github entry, right click *TOTP > Show TOTP*, click *Copy* then paste the generated TOTP under *Verify the code from the app*.

*Note: Save the `recovery codes` since you may require one of these codes to authenticate to Github as an alternate/recovery method in the event of loss of device etc.*

Use KeePassXC's **Show TOTP** feature to create TOTP in addition to your other login credentials every time you connect to Github.

Now you won't need to install a third-party authenticator or rely on a mobile device to log in to Github; only your laptop or local workstation will do.

You can watch the following videos for instructions on configuring KeePassXC with 2FA integration.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FE6rr-qxllA
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VEfkt29moE8

Answer (score 1):

If you manage to install android emulator or virtual machine on your PC (unfortunately, I cannot help with it) and than install https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2 on it, its possible to use this instance of Google Authenticator for tricking GitHub you have 2 factor authentication. But I think this approach is something that degrades security dramatically. If your PC is stolen or hacked, someone could access you authenticator and misuse it.

UPD: you can emulate a 2 factor authentication device with this library in nodejs (probably, analogous libraries exists in other programming languages):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/notp

This method can work - https://www.npmjs.com/package/notp#totpgenkey-opt

Update: There is CLI application that does this exact thing
https://github.com/grijul/zauth

Comment: According to Wikipedia, Google Authenticator uses "Time-based One-time Password Algorithm (TOTP; specified in RFC 6238) and HMAC-based One-time Password algorithm (HOTP; specified in RFC 4226)". You could probably fine a native Desktop app (for Windows, Linux, macOS, whatever) which does with without needing a VM

Comment: You can use [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/) with the [pass-otp](https://github.com/tadfisher/pass-otp) as well. This [blog article](https://oem.github.io/blog/2021-09-27--using-2fa-otp-with-pass__cli_public.html) describes how to set this up on Arch Linux.