# How to do Github 2FA without phone?

Tags: authentication, github

Well, Github is asking to activate 2FA. But when I go to proceed, I'm asked to install some apps and flash a QR code. However, I have no smartphone (and no dumb phone either.) How the earth to proceed then?

From that page I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a free way to set up GitHub 2FA without a mobile device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68824508/is-there-a-free-way-to-set-up-github-2fa-without-a-mobile-device)